# How can react suspense remain on the same page -LazyLoading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

How can I make Reacts Suspense not show any fallback but rather stay on the same page
This what I have

```
return (
      <Router>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <Fragment>
            <Switch>
              <Layout>
                <Suspense fallback={<BusyIndicator />} maxDuration={5000}>
                  <PrivateRoute
                    exact
                    path="/en/account/dashboard"
                    component={Home}
                  />
                  <PrivateRoute exact path="/en/books" component={Books} />
                  <PrivateRoute
                    exact
                    path="/en/account/quiz"
                    component={Quiz}
                  />

                  <PrivateRoute
                    exact
                    path="/en/account/quiz/:slug"
                    component={QuizDetail}
                  />
                  <PrivateRoute
                    exact
                    path="/en/account/quiz/:slug/result"
                    component={QuizResult}
                  />

                  <PrivateRoute
                    exact
                    path="/en/account/my-books"
                    component={MyBooks}
                  />
                  <PrivateRoute
                    exact
                    path="/en/account/logout"
                    component={Logout}
                  />
                  <RedirectRoute
                    exact
                    path="/en/register"
                    component={Register}
                  />
                  <RedirectRoute exact path="/en/login" component={Login} />
                </Suspense>
              </Layout>
              <Route component={NoMatch} />
            </Switch>
          </Fragment>
        </Provider>
      </Router>
    );
```

What I want is for the page to render the same component it is on until it has fetched the next chunk, maybe with a top progress bar like youtube

Comment: `BusyIndicator` is what you see till your component is ready, so you can style it whatever you want.

Comment: I know but what I want is for it to just stay on the same page until the next one is ready

Comment: I want it to render the same component until the promise has resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@NduJay I think what you are looking for is a resolver. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-resolver

Basically the concept is that the next component won't render until the data requirements to show it have been met.